# How would one go about building pluggable software?

Tags: design, plugins, extensibility

If you have an application of some sort and you want your users to be able to write plugins for it, how should the application be designed?

What do you have to take into account, what design patterns are for this etc?

Comment: Patterns like Observer, Mediator,Command ad Chain of Responsibility come to mind

Comment: @Mchl: Please post your answer as an answer, not as a comment.

Comment: You should take a look at [Mef](http://mef.codeplex.com/) and the [MSDN info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee291628.aspx)

Comment: I feel it to be not detailed enough for that

Comment: @Mchl: "not detailed enough"?  Then why comment at all?  It's clearly an answer.  Please post answers as answers.

Answer (score 15):

It kinda depends on your platform but some general things to keep in mind

**Versioning**
What happens if you update your application, does all old plugins become obsolete (the firefox problem)

**Isolation**
Can plugins do whatever they want? Do you always trust them? Or do you need to run them in some sort of sandbox and request  permissions.

**Updates**
How do you handle plugin-updates?

**Security**
How do you ensure the author of a plugin, prevent spoofing or the user being tricked into installing malicious code. Usually solved by some sort of code-signing

**Serialization**
Often when you use isolation of some sort you need to serialize information between different threads or processes. How do you do that most efficiently?

**Extensibility**
What aspects do you need to extend? How do you maximize the potential of plugins without the API becoming unwieldy.

If you're targeting third-party developers for plugins I'd say the most important thing (from my experience) is to see the plugin api and classes as completely different from the rest of the application, and make it as easy to develop for as possible. It's very easy for architecture from the main app to "bleed over" into the plugins so that plugin authors have to learn much more than they have to. Make it easy for them, think on what kind of interface  and experience you'd want as a plugin author.

Another good mindset is not to think like "The plugin will do all these things (in code) but rather, "the plugin needs to provide this information". That way the application can consume the necessary information and do the actual processing which will simplify the plugin.

Also in general, whenever you can go a descriptive approach (metadata, like xml) rather than code you have a big advantage since metadata is easier to transport, version, deploy, secure and can more easily be configured by third-parties

Comment: +1 It does not directly answer the question, but these are important issues to have in mind

Comment: I believe these issues are covered before anyone starts developing the actual extensibility mechanism

Answer (score 10):

I wrote this [Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/SoapBoxCorePinBallDemo.aspx) about using MEF for extensibility in .NET.  It's a good introduction.

There are other extensibility frameworks for .NET, such as [SharpDevelop's Add-in Architecture](http://sharpdevelop.net/TechNotes/ProgramArchitecture.pdf), [Mono.Addins](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono.Addins) and [System.AddIn](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/08/13/Build-AddIns-with-System-AddIn.aspx).

For Java, there is the [Eclipse Plug-in Architecture](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Plug-in-architecture/plugin_architecture.html).

The general pattern is this:

- You define a contract (normally an interface) between the host and the extension
- You need a discovery mechanism that goes out and looks for installed extensions
- You need to be able to dynamically load the extensions and make the host aware of them

In practice it shares a lot with Dependency Injection and the Strategy Pattern.

Comment: +1 MEF and System.AddIn are both good things to look at.  Even if you don't end up using them they both show good concepts.

Comment: @jkohlhepp - I agree, and I would also suggest a deep dive into the SharpDevelop architecture because there's a lot written about it, it's open source (so is MEF, btw), and it's well designed.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to provide an interface for the plugins.

It should contain at least an Activate-Methode (an entry point), but you'll want things like Initialize etc. as well.

And there should be the possibility to communicate with the host application in a registry-like manner, for example to register menu items. So registries for things that are changeable/extendable for plugins should be provided.

Also, there should be some accessible storage for the host application's data and objects, so plugins can call its routines. This can easily be done by using a DI-Container like Unity and letting the plugins access it, so they can resolve the services they need.

An Event-Aggregator is probably a good idea also, so the plugins can throw events and react to events from other plugins and the host application in a decoupled manner. You definitely want one!